# How to use ResourceManager and resources file in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, system, resourcemanager

I have the following method:

```
    private void SetResources(string filename = ResxFileName)
    {
        if (_resourceManager == null)
        {
            _resourceManager = new ResourceManager(filename + ".Strings", GetType().Assembly);
        }
    }
```

If ResxFileName = "Example", where would Example.Strings.resx need to be located in the project in order for it to be accessed? I've tried placing it in the Properties of the project under the Solution Explorer, but whenever GetString("ExampleString") is called and ExampleString exists as a Name and has a value in Example.Strings.resx, I get the following System.Exception:

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure \"Example.Strings.resources\" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly \"ProjectName\" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

I've tried running Custom Tool and ensured that the Build Action is set to "Embedded Resource", as others who have posted similar issues have mentioned. These solutions have **not** resolved the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to flip the filename, `Strings` would be the filename.

As to where to place the files, it depends , for a web project it should be in `App_GlobalResources`

Try this

```
private void SetResources(string filename = ResxFileName)
{
    if (_resourceManager == null)
    {
        Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources");
        _resourceManager = new ResourceManager("Resources." + filename, assembly);
    }
}
```

For example you would put `Strings.en-US`, `Strings.fr` resource files in the `App_GlobalResources` folder.

EDIT:

I don't know what to add, this is the correct way of doing, for the sake of time, I created a demo project for you.

<kbd>[DEMO DOWNLOAD](https://mega.nz/#!GAYhhCwS!eZa1Ifg9najmLNpcaljYNDY8jZzYK6OuFs4GDT8ja10)</kbd>

Look inside of the `HomeController` to see the example.

Comment: It looks like I have an App_LocalResources folder, but whenever I add that line of code that you added to the method, and placed the my .resx file into that folder, I'm receiving an exception that states that the file or assembly "App_LocalResources" could not be loaded.

Comment: the first part of the string is the namespace the second one would be the resource filename, but dont put the extensions. Show me the hardcoded value

Comment: I have a project called MVC. I have a solution folder inside MVC called App_LocalResources. I have moved ControllerResources.resx to the App_LocalResources folder. I have the following code that has been simplified for the sake this issue, https://dotnetfiddle.net/OkDXsO

Comment: Ur code is different look at mine again. put the namespace `resource.` follwed by the ressource file name. Your code does the opposite so it would look for a file called String in the namespace with that filename value

Comment: Now I'm getting a System.IO.FileNotFoundException like before stating that the file or assembly "App_LocalResources" could not be loaded, based on this code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8t6tTO

Comment: bro see my edit I just did, I put a sample project for you

Comment: Well, the demo is still available, so points for that. (Wow!)